# Display only days on django template

Tags: django

I'm trying to display the difference between 2 giving dates on django, and i've managed to make it, but now i'm strugling to display only the days, without the time, is there any filter that i can use?

**My html template:**

```
<a href="{% url 'edit_contract' contract.id %}">
    {% if contract.status == 'PN'  %}
        {{ today |sub:contract.starting_date  }}
    {% else %}
        TODO
    {% endif %}
</a>
```

**My view:**

```
@login_required
def contract_list(request):
    contracts = Contract.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    total_contracts_value = Contract.objects.filter(user=request.user).aggregate(sum=Sum('value'))['sum'] or 0
    contracts_count = Contract.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
    today = date.today()
    return render(request, 'list_contract.html', {'contracts': contracts,
                                                       'total_contracts_value': total_contracts_value,
                                                       'contracts_count': contracts_count, 'today':today})
```

My output:
[image: Output print]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few ways to do what you want here. I'll let you decide what you think works best for you.

1. The `timesince` or `timeuntil` template formatting tags within Django may give you what you want immediately.

`{{ today |timeuntil:contract.starting_date }}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#timeuntil

2. Another option is to make use of the `datetime` module.

Here is an example showing the difference in days between datetime objects:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
startingDate = now + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
daysRemaining = (startingDate-now).days
print(daysRemaining) # INFO: prints '7'
```

I don't think this is what you want, but here is another example, using `strftime` and `timedelta` to get more specific formatting:

```
tomorrowFormatted = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1), "%d-%b-%Y")
```

Comment: Love it! That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Days since start is a property of your contract, so you could create an actual property in the Contract model

```
from datetime import date
from django.db import models

class Contract(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def days_since_start(self):
        today = date.today()
        result = today - self.start_date
        return result.days
```

then refer to the property in your template

```
    {% if contract.status == 'PN'  %}
            {{ contract.days_since_start }}
    {% else %}
```